# Where is this function's callback getting its arguments from?

Tags: php, functions, globals, callbacks, parameter

This might be better suited to Stack Overflow, thought I'd try here first though.

I was walking through [this tutorial by Justin Tadlock](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/04/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/) and encountered the function below being used as the callback argument for the `add_meta_box` function. My questions concern the parameters...

```
function smashing_post_class_meta_box( $object, $box ) {

wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'smashing_post_class_nonce' );

$output = '<p>';
$output .= '<label for="smashing-post-class">Add a custom CSS class, which will be applied to WordPress\' post class.</label>';
$output .= '<br />';
$output .= '<input class="widefat" type="text" name="smashing-post-class" id="smashing-post-class" value="' . esc_attr( get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'smashing_post_class', true ) ) . '" size="30" />';
$output .= '</p>';

echo $output;
}
```

I'm assuming `$object` is the global `$post` object? Where does it come from, how does it get passed into the callback? It also seems as though `$box` is unused, is that some sort of PHP in/out parameter? I've seen this kind of stuff scattered around WordPress, and my PHP knowledge is limited to WP so I'm not sure what exactly I'm seeing. I did a quick search at PHP.net and around the Codex, any info would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look at function `do_meta_boxes()` in wp-admin/includes/template.php then you'll see this line close to the end of the function:

```
call_user_func($box['callback'], $object, $box);
```

That calls the callback function and provides the two arguments. The `$box` argument holds all the information about the metabox, like ID, title, callback function.

In wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php, which displays your post edit/create screen, you can see the do_meta_boxes calls in action, e.g.:

```
do_meta_boxes(null, 'advanced', $post);
```

So, in that case `$object`would indeed be a post object. In other cases, like the dashboard screen, $object is actually set to an empty string.

It might be worth noting that `add_meta_box()` just adds to the `$wp_meta_boxes` global. In `do_meta_boxes()` that global then gets looped through and the boxes are being displayed.